# SupressSystemOverlays in Windows Phone 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone

I would like to hide the soft keys and the tool tray in this Windows Phone 10 Universal App.

```
            var x = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
            x.SuppressSystemOverlays = true;
```

I tried this, which msdn seems to suggest would do it, but the true value does not take. It remains false after the line executes.

How can I hide those darn overlays. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After throwing everything at it and trying every switch in the ApplicationView class, the only one that worked on the Windows 10 Phone Universal App was:

TryEnterFullScreenMode();

The other switches had no effect at all.   Hope it helps somebody!